# Stop automatic resize in axes

Tags: matlab

I use this code to load an image into matlab axes in gui :

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','PLease select an image');

axes(handles.axes1)
rgb = imread(strcat(PathName,FileName));
imagesc(200,200,rgb)
```

my problem is that when i load the image the axes automatically resizes to the image size , any way to stop this ? "i googled alot" !

and when it comes to big images (like 1 MB) it takes about 30 seconds to load and display it !!! any workaround for faster loading ?

i want to make edge detection for the loaded image and display it in second axes , any sources/code to do it ?

am a beginner in matlap can you please help ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the axes limits using `xlim()` and `ylim()` matlab will set the 'XLimMode' and 'YLimMode' properties of the axes to 'manual' so the limits will not change later.

```
figure;
hold all;
xlim([1 2.5]);
ylim([3 4]);
plot([1 2], [3 4]);
plot([2 3], [3 4]);
```

For edge detection, take a look at the matlab help in the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/description5.html) to get started.